# Need help with android WebView

Tags: android, variables, webview, global

I am new to Android and java development. I create a WebView object in the OnCreate function. Now I need to be able to pass this same object to other functions in the code, such as the onOptionsItemSelected function. I currently have it where I just create a new WebView object in each function where I need it, but this slows down the code since it has to recreate it and such.

Comment: little confused as to what you are asking. Do you want to just make it a class variable so your functions can access the single instance?

Comment: Yeah, that might work. I just need them able to access the variable without having to recreate it.

Comment: Nothing else in the same class would have to recreate the object.. they can just access the field.

Comment: Then yes, making it a class variable is what I would recommend.

Answer (score 1):

Something as simple as this?

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    WebView wv;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        wv = new WebView(this);
        setContentView(wv);

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem  item){
        wv.doSomething();
    }
```